# Spring Integration and JPA transactions

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration

I'm using Spring integration to receive XML formal XMPP messages :

```
<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter id="xmppInboundAdapter" channel="xmppInbound" xmpp-connection="xmppConnection" auto-startup="true" />
<int:channel id="xmppInbound" />
<int:service-activator ref="messageRouterService" input-channel="xmppInbound" />
```

I have already some persistence features and it works (storing messages in database, analysing message compared to what's in database, ...).

Now I have a method which need to be transactional because I need to initialize 2 collections related to 1 entity, so the second collection is lazy initialized by calling a method on it.

This works fine in JUnit, but what do I need to do to make it work in the main code ? Can I just put @Transactional at any level, or does it need to be at the root of the whole process or even declared in some way in the inbound adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hard work with JPA and database is really just in the mentioned `messageRouterService`, then it is indeed should be enough to mark that service method with the `@Transactional` annotation and refer properly to your `JpaTransactionManager`.

If think to make the whole flow as transactional, then it isn't possible starting with the `<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter>` because there is no hooks to inject `TransactionInterceptor`. However you can use a `TransactionInterceptorBuilder(true)` to produce a `TransactionHandleMessageAdvice` which will wraps the whole sub-flow starting with the adviced endpoint via its `<request-handler-advice-chain>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: Could u just be more precise about "refer properly to your JpaTransactionManager" ? I have a "@EnableTransactionManagement" annotation on a configuration class, and this class declare a jpaTransactionManager bean, I need more you think ?

Comment: No, that's enough. I was more concerned when you would have more than one `TransactionManager`..